# Authentication failed for a private github repo in my self-hosted runner (with PAT)

Tags: go, github, github-actions

I've a git runner setup in my gcloud instance. It is running and showing up in my runners' list. Problem occurs when my go project I'm trying to build is using a private github module.

Here are the steps I've followed:

- exposed environment variable: GOPRIVATE=github.com/<MY_ORG>/<MY_REPO>
- git config --global
  url."https://<PRIAVTE_ACCESS_TOKEN>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf
  "https://github.com/"

But I'm still getting the following error when I'm trying to access the private module:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<MY_ORG>/<MY_REPO>/'

My github action workflow file looks like this:

```
name: CICD
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
     inputs:
        ENV:
            description: 'ENV'
            required: true
            default: 'poc'
        DOCKER_TAG:
            description: 'docker image tag'
            required: true
            default: 'latest'
env:
  NS: ${{ vars.NS }}
  ENV: ${{ github.event.inputs.ENV }}
  DOCKER_TAG: ${{ github.event.inputs.DOCKER_TAG }}
  GOOS: ${{ vars.GOOS }}
  GOARCH: ${{ vars.GOARCH }}
  CGO_ENABLED: ${{ vars.CGO_ENABLED }}
  GKE_SA_KEY: ${{ secrets.GKE_SA_KEY }}
  GKE_CLUSTER: ${{ vars.GKE_CLUSTER }}
  GKE_ZONE : ${{ vars.GKE_ZONE }}
  DOCKER_REG: ${{ vars.DOCKER_REG }}
  PROJECT_ID:  ${{ vars.PROJECT_ID }}
  DOCKER_REPO:  ${{ vars.DOCKER_REPO }}
  APP_NAME:  ${{ vars.APP_NAME }}
  DOMAIN: ${{ vars.DOMAIN }}
  URL: ${{ vars.URL }}
  GOPRIVATE : ${{ vars.GOPRIVATE }}
  TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITPAT }}

jobs:
  app-build:
    environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.ENV }}
    runs-on: my-self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Configure git for private modules
        run: git config --global url."https://$TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
      - name: Build
        run: go build -o main main.go     <---- FAILING OVER HERE
```

Here the project I'm trying to build depends upon a private github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar issue while trying to install modules from a private repository. Following are some of my findings:

1. Github actions generates a unique authentication token at the start of the workflow which has access only to the current repository.
2. By default when we checkout the repository with actions/checkout, it stores the token in local github config
3. In order to override it using ‘github config’ command, we must set ‘persist-credentials’ to false.

My github actions workflow looks like this:

```
 - name: checkout
   uses: actions/checkout@v3
   with:
     persist-credentials: false
 - name: npm install
   run: |
     git config —global url.”https://${{ secrets.MY_GIT_TOKEN }}@github.com/“.insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/
     npm install
```

Comment: hey @Nadeem, this didnt help in my case. I'm still facing the same issue.